# how to use Machine translation service to translate a word document

Tags: 2013

I am new to this service application. I want to translate a word document or any other document using manchine translation service. how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To use Machine translation service to translate a word document,first create a new translation service.

Below Powershell script can be used to create new powershell service.

```
New-SPTranslationServiceApplication -Name "Machine Translation Service Application" -DatabaseName "MachineTranslationDB" -DatabaseServer "ContosoDBServer" -ApplicationPool "ContosoAppPool" -Default
```

To make configuration changes or for adding extensions to machine translation service use below powershell script

```
Set-SPTranslationServiceApplication -Identity "Machine Translation Service Application" -EnableAllFileExtensions -UseDefaultlnternetSettings -TimerJobFrequency 30 -MaximumTranslationAttempts 3 -JobExpirationDays 14 -MaximumSyncTranslationRequests 20 -RecycleProcessThreshold 300 -DisableBinaryFileScan 1
```

The default interval of the translation timer job is 15 minutes.

Open the document as we can see “Translate” option to translate the document.
[image]

By clicking that we can see the prompt to change the language as shown the image below.

[image]

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj553772.aspx

Comment: I have machine service application in my system and its status is started. but when i try to open a word doc am not getting those options which you showed in the screen shot ??

Comment: How are you opening those documents.Do you have office web app installed

Comment: No i don have office web app. Is there any other way i could get those options to translate